# Use HttpClient to send two POST requests 2 seconds apart

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm trying to write an integration test for a DelegatingHandler that prevents duplicate requests.  The handler checks a database to see if the request is already being processed and returns a 407-Conflict if a duplicate request is made while the previous request is still running.

I have the following code in my test:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var responseTask1 = client.PostAsJsonAsync(RequestUriWithDuplicatePrevention, ReadRequestContent("DuplicateRequestJsonContent.json"));
var responseTask2 = client.PostAsJsonAsync(RequestUriWithDuplicatePrevention, ReadRequestContent("DuplicateRequestJsonContent.json"));

var response1 = responseTask1.Result;
var response2 = responseTask2.Result;
```

Both requests are being logged into the database at the exact same time.  How can I delay the second request for a period of time?

I've tried adding a Thread.Sleep(500) but it didn't seem to make a difference.

**Revised Code**

This code seems to work most of the time but it not 100% reliable.

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldReturn407ConflictWhenDuplicateRequestSubmitted()
    {
        var results = ExecutePostRequests().Result;

        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, results[0].StatusCode);
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, results[1].StatusCode);
    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage[]> ExecutePostRequests()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var task1 = ExecutePost(client, 0);
        var task2 = ExecutePost(client, 4000);

        var response1 = await task1;
        var response2 = await task2;

        return new[] {response1, response2};
    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecutePost(HttpClient client, int delay)
    {
        await Task.Delay(delay);
        return await client.PostAsync(RequestUriWithDuplicatePrevention,
            ReadRequestContent("DuplicateRequestJsonContent.json"));
    }
```

The web service being executed has a Thread.Sleep(5000).

Comment: You put a `Thread.Sleep(500)` call between assignment of `responseTask1` and `responseTask2` and yet the receiver got them at the "exact same time."  Did you try larger delays?  I find it very surprising `HttpClient` would delay making the first request.  Could this be explained by be other factors such as the network or your receiving code?

Comment: Your revised code looks like it should work to me. What do you mean by "not 100% reliable"?

Comment: By 'not 100% reliable' means that the test fails every so often but running it again straight away is successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific problem in your original code is that it is sleeping *between getting results*, when you should be sleeping *between starting the asynchronous operations*.

It could be corrected like so:

```
var responseTask1 = client.PostAsJsonAsync(...);
Thread.Sleep(2000);
var responseTask2 = client.PostAsJsonAsync(...);

var response1 = responseTask1.Result;
var response2 = responseTask2.Result;
```

Your revised code does not suffer this issue and should work. Though, I would change this:

```
    var response1 = await task1;
    var response2 = await task2;

    return new[] {response1, response2};
```

To a more efficient:

```
    return await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```